# Merge Tags: findduplicates and Duplicates-management

Tags: feature-request

ATTN : Mods

The find Duplicates has a single question related, and it can/should be merged with the Duplicaes-management tag

Comment: Is that something a Mod can do or is it a case where we need to have several users who have sufficient reputation on that tag to vote for the merge? Clarification on that to your question would be helpful, especially since you're a former Mod and I'd expect you might already know the answer to the question on how it needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks CRM, my mod days have long passed :-), but Yes, it's a MOD's action.